# Firefox 32 - hijacked all Adobe PDFs and turned them to "firefox HTML"?

Tags: firefox

My operating system is (still) Windows XP. Firefox 32.0.3 is my default browser. Eversince installing this latest Firefox, all my Adobe PDF file icons have changed to Firefox HTML icons. My pointer toll tip info says they are HTML too.

BUT, the strange thing is,the file extension says they are ".pdf " ! I tried a few changes from the "folder options" tab in windows, but it keeps telling that PDF default type is the "firefox HTML document". I find this very strange indeed. The only way I was able to get rid of this HTML hijacking is by removing / uninstalling Firefox ! then all my pdf files are back to adobe pdf icons and open by adobe reader XI as it does normally.

Removing Firefox is not an option for me. I need a solution to keep Firefox and use it with Windows XP normally as many other XP systems around me. Thank you in advance if any of you could help.

Regards,
JM

Answer (score 2):

Reinstall FireFox, it will probably associate itself as the system PDF handler again as before (perhaps check for advanced options that allow you to tell it to NOT do that during install, making this all moot).

Then, tell Windows to use Adobe Reader as the default PDF handler:

- Right-click a PDF file, and choose "Open With..."
- Choose Adobe Reader as the program to open it with (you *may* need to browse for it).
- Ensure "Always use the eslected program to open this kind of file".
- Hit OK to apply the changes.

Adobe Reader should now be the default PDF handler again, and the icons should change (back) to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just right click on one of these file's > Open With > Choose Default Program,
and set Adobe Reader as the default program?

Answer (score 0):

Go to control panel....Folder Options then File types....scroll down to Firefox HTML Document....then  un associate with PDF

Comment: Can you describe in a little more detail the *steps* the user must take?

Answer (score 0):

Why is removing Firefox not an option? It is meddling with your computer settings without your permission! Who knows what garbage it will inflict on you with the next update! Get rid of Firefox, at least until it starts to behave with more decency.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).